ASP.NET Core MVC : return view and then redirect to another one
I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I have code like this in my controller:
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}

The ConfirmEmail view will be returned and rendered. But after showing this ConfirmEmail view, I want to redirect to another route automatically and show another view.
How can I do that? Could you guide me, please?
Probably, it should have be done from my ConfirmEmail.cshtml view. So is there any way to call some redirect C# function after ConfirmEmail.cshtml rendering? Or something like that?

You need to learn about how HTTP works first: a HTTP response, alone, cannot do what you describe - so it's usually done with a HTML reponse with some client JavaScript - but this is not 100% reliable.

Only one response can be sent to the client.  If that response is a page (view) then any redirect afterward would need to be done in client-side code (JavaScript).

I know that I can't do that from this code in controller. But it's ASP NET MVC - framework I mean, So probably it should be possible via framework tools in .csthml code for example via C# code. That's what I looking for

@AlexK.: If you're looking to perform a redirect from client-side code then what you're looking for is this.  (The immediate usefulness of which depends on your familiarity with JavaScript, which we don't know.  There may be a learning curve there as well.)

MVC is a server-side rendered framework so that The ConfirmEmail view will be returned and rendered means the cshtml already rendered completely and the c# code already finished its task in this request, the rest shall be handled by the client side, maybe start a new request to Controller via js code. So after showing this ConfirmEmail view, I want to redirect to another route should be done by client js code.

Ok I just had an idea that maybe it's possible to do that without js code, using some C# directives I mean from .cshtml files.
Thank you for comments


Probably, it should have be done from my ConfirmEmail.cshtml view.

Indeed it should.  This is because an HTTP response can only have one response.  A page (view) is a response, and a redirect ("location header") is a response.  The controller can only return one or the other, not both.

So is there any way to call some redirect C# function after ConfirmEmail.cshtml rendering?

C# runs server-side.  By the time the view is rendered in the browser, the server-side code has already executed on the server and is done.
After returning a view, you can redirect in client-side code.  For example, if the view contains this:
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.replace("@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")");
</script>

Then the resulting client-side code would be something like:
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.replace("/controller/action");
</script>

This would immediately redirect the user to that URL.  If you don't want it to be immediate then you could put it inside of a timeout:
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace("@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")");
  }, 5000);
</script>

The value 5000 indicates that the operation should be performed after 5000 ms (5 seconds).

Thank you for the answer! Just to be clear: I was looking for something like this in Blazor (Razor pages) but in MVC: "@inject NavigationManager UriHelper
@code {
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
UriHelper.NavigateTo("login");
}
} " Because my idea was to use only C# and framework tools :) But thank you, I've got it know
